# How get phone state or sms state?

Tags: android, sms, state

Hello all i will explain my question a little more. I'm not native english speaker. So maybe my question is on the internet but when i search i only found something i already know.

I have a Xperia U with the illumination barre. I use it as a notification for sms. I already know how to receiver SMS and the event of unlock screen

What i will now is 2 thing.

1- Possibility to know if the last sms was read by the user or not(My apllication is just a notification center and not a sms handler so the sms reading is doing by official app or user app like gosms)

2- Possibility to know if phone is already unlock, i will remove notification if it is.

I'm not very clear but i find this difficult to explain if you don't undestand the question say it i will reformulate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Possibility to know if the last sms was read by the user or not(My apllication is just a notification center and not a sms handler so the sms reading is doing by official app or user app like gosms)

There is no concept of Read in SMS. You can get a delivery notification for when it reaches the user's device, but you can't tell if the user read it or not.

> Possibility to know if phone is already unlock, i will remove notification if it is.

You will need to dynamically register a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_SCREEN_ON and ACTION_USER_PRESENT broadcasts.

Comment: i have already this one android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT for remove light but it work only when the screen is lock 
if the screen is unlock and the user do something this event is not call a second time is this normal?

Comment: @Jebik Yeah, that's the normal behaviour.

Comment: so if i undestand , i need to check all unlock and all lock by recevier and set a shared pref for know if the mobile is lock or not when i get a sms ? no more simple?

Comment: Just check if there has been an ACTION_SCREEN_OFF since the last ACTION_USER_PRESENT. If there has, then its locked. If there hasn't, then its unlocked. Simple enough

Comment: yep but i must store this data because my app is just a recevier who launch a service i was thinking it have a method somewhere like iSLock() but apparently not thank for help i will try this

Comment: @Jebik Just keep a flag in your shared preference and set it in the receiver for the actions.

Comment: I have a lot of difficult because screen_OFF is not a normal action but now this work like i want thank